# How to use layout for sendgrid template?

Tags: c#, sendgrid

Is it possible to have one html layout for several sendgrid email templates? Are there any examples? If I have layout A and template B, I want to specify just B template id when I send email.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by layout vs template? Isn't that the same thing? The template either uses a design editor or HTML editor. When you create a template, that template ID can be given when sending an email, [like so](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/how-to-send-an-email-with-dynamic-templates#send-a-transactional-email).

Comment: @AnthonyDellavecchia I want to specify in layout common styles, wrapper for inner html. Pseudocode for template { LayoutId = MyId,  <span> I am template</span> }.  Pseudocode for layout { <body class='centered'> Render() </body> }. I want to have one common wrapper for all emails.